# What do you get when you complete all Charlie's 4E missions?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

I see many items that requires completing all Grim's missions first in order to purchase. However, I finished all Charlie's missions but I didn't find anything exclusive that I can buy now, is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You get the best torso armor for your ops suit.